# Add folder name to output Pig Latin

Tags: date, hadoop, logging, text, apache-pig

I have next directory structure in HDFS:

```
logs_folder
   |---2021-03-01
          |---log1
          |---log2
          |---log3
       2021-03-02
          |---log1
          |---log2
       2021-03-03
          |---log1
          |---log2
...
```

Logs are made up of text data. There is no date in the data because it is already in the folder name. I want to read all the logs and save them in the following format:

```
date    id
```

where id - field from the log, but I need to take the date from the folder name.
Expected output:

```
2021-03-01    id1
2021-03-01    id2
...
2021-03-02    id234
2021-03-02    id456
...
```

**How to add date from folder name to output?**

---

I found close question how to add full pathname to data on reading:

```
A = LOAD '/logs_folder/*' using PigStorage(',','-tagPath'); 
DUMP A  ;
```

[How can I incorporate the current input filename into my Pig Latin script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751480/how-can-i-incorporate-the-current-input-filename-into-my-pig-latin-script)

It is very close, but how to get parent folder name only instead of full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used this approach:

1. Load data using `-tagPathz attribute - it adds column to loaded data contains full path to every file
2. Use regex to filter parent folder only

Code example:

```
hadoop_data = LOAD '/logs_folder/*' USING PigStorage(',', '-tagPath') as (filepath:chararray, id:chararray, feature:chararray, value:chararray);
hadoop_data = FOREACH hadoop_data GENERATE id,(chararray)REGEX_EXTRACT(filepath,'.*\\/(.*)\\/',1) as path,
    feature,value;
```

My data consist of 3 fields - id, feature, value, but you can see there are 4 of them - `filepath` field was added!